# Sub Queries in Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using postgres as a database in my application.

In that I have a jsonb column and for storing json data inside it.

```
{
    "id": "manohar",
    "array": [
        {
            "status": "active",
            "date": "13/12/2022"
        },
        {
            "status": "InActive",
            "date": "13/12/2021"
        }
    ]
}
```

so here every time I'm writing subqueries to select any field based on maximum date inside an array object.
Problem here is I have 100's of fields in each json object so every time I have to write subqueries for each feild.

and after using subqueries looks less in performance.

Here is the Query that I'm using

```
Select 

(select t.sub_array->>'status'
from tbl_name d
  cross join lateral (
     select t.item  as sub_array
     from jsonb_array_elements(d.column_name -> 'array') as t(item)
      where t.item ->> 'date' <= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
     order by (t.item ->> 'date')::date desc
     limit 1
 ) t where t.primaryKey = d.key) as status

--like I have to write 100 subqueries for 100's fields 

from tbl_name t
where t.id='3'
```

I don't want to use Views for this requirements.

Any better approach or suggestions will be helpful..

Thanks..

Comment: Storing JSON is not part of the good pratices in SQL. You should explode the content of the JSON in tables/lines (see [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)) to increase read performances.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `lateral view` to access a JSON. But storing and accessing a JSON in a DB is not part of the best practices in SQL.

In your case, I can only advise you to change your data model. Storing JSON is one thing, you can use `blob` string to store it, that should be ok.
But at the same time you write it, you should also explode its content in tables/columns/lines. Therefore, you can then access its content more easily.

The idea is :

- either you take time to write it properly (make a nice data architecture)
- or you take time to read it properly (make complexe SQL queries)

---

This is just an example of what you should do. You probably need to find pretty names to reflect the business value of each of your objects.

**table "id"**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | manohar |

**table "id_status"**

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | InActive | 13/12/2021 |
| 1 | Active | 13/12/2022 |